# Google play console how to "detach", "unrelease" old builds apk

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

This question is about Google play console and the App bundle explorer; how to detach or remove from a release so that I can delete a old apk ???

Issue : when I upload a new version, it gets rejected because of older builds, in the appeal they say version 3 and 4 don't comply blablabla, but I'm sending like build 20

how can I unrealese or detach old builds from production and open testing...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

1- you cannot remove older builds once sent for aproval

2- you need to upload a new .aab in "App bundle explorer"

3- go to "Internal testing" and create a new release with "add from library"

4- go to "Closed testing" and create a new release with "add from library"

5- go to "Open testing" and create a new release with "add from library"

6- go to "Production" and create a new release with "add from library"

7- ONLY when you modified ALL testing + production to the latest build, then you can go to "Releases overview" and apply or send for review

When I had the issue, some older rejected builds were in open testing and that was the rejection => for the old build.....

Make sure to have the latest build in release in all : production and all testings...

Comment: So you can't get rid of an older build that failed to be approved?